# jQuery click event executes function one more time after ajax call

Tags: jquery, click, execute

```
$(document).on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.play', function(event) {
        var slider_icons_wrapper = $('#slider_icons_wrapper');

        slider_icons_wrapper.attr('class', 'pause');
        autoSlider(cur_img_div_pos);
        showButton('play_icon');
        console.log('play');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.pause', function(event) {
        var slider_icons_wrapper = $('#slider_icons_wrapper');

        slider_icons_wrapper.attr('class', 'play');
        clearInterval(inter);
        showButton('pause_icon');
        console.log('pause');
    });
```

This code works fine for the first time the document is loaded.
When user navigates to another page, via ajax call (document does not refresh), and returns to the page that contains #slider_icons_wrapper div, the function executes twice when user clicks this div. If user navigates again and return, the function executes 3 times and so on!

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit#1**

When user navigates to another page, element #slider_icons_wrapper is removed from the DOM. When it is injected back via ajax call, the click event is firing on more time, each time. I have tried to unbind the click event when user leaves this page but the same thing happens

Comment: It looks like there is a selector conflict. I would change the ID in the html to `#slider_icons_wrapper_play` and `#slider_icons_wrapper_pause`.

Comment: I want to select a div with id="slider_icons_wrapper" and class="play" or "pause"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the event listener is being added to the document for every page return.  try adding them on document.ready --

```
function init(e){

    $(document).on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.play', function(event) {
        var slider_icons_wrapper = $('#slider_icons_wrapper');

        slider_icons_wrapper.attr('class', 'pause');
        autoSlider(cur_img_div_pos);
        showButton('play_icon');
        console.log('play');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.pause', function(event) {
        var slider_icons_wrapper = $('#slider_icons_wrapper');

        slider_icons_wrapper.attr('class', 'play');
        clearInterval(inter);
        showButton('pause_icon');
        console.log('pause');
    });

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

user1026361 also makes a good point to remove your listeners before adding them again. however, I believe that using .off(  ) without a selector will remove all listeners added to that element via .on(  ).  if you take the .off(  ).on(  ) approach I would suggest using a namespace:

```
$(document).off('click.clickPlay').on('click.clickPlay', '#slider_icons_wrapper.play', function(event) {
    ...
});

$(document).off('click.clickPause').on('click.clickPause', '#slider_icons_wrapper.pause', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried your idea and user1026361 as well, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the code where your event handlers are set upon "navigate and return", you are probably assigning multiple handlers to the same event.

Try using these statements:

```
$(document).off().on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.play', function(event) {

$(document).off().on('click', '#slider_icons_wrapper.pause', function(event) {
```

to clear your handlers before reassigning them

You should always clear your handlers and be careful that the place where you assign them is only seen once per page view.

Comment: .off() will remove all event handlers, better is to use .off('click')

Comment: roasted is correct.  Because you know the event on the element, you can be explicit in it's removal.  I typically remove all before adding all, so the above works better for me